# which-function-mode only in python buffers

Tags: header-line, which-function-mode

How can I restrict the `which-func-mode` and the header bar to `python-mode` buffers only?

I like to use `which-func-mode` in the `headline` for Python files/buffers only.
In my current config it works that the mode is activated only if a `python-mode` buffer comes up.
But the problem is that after that the `which-func-mode` and the `headline` is shown in all buffers.

```
;; =========
;; Which Function Mode
;; =========
(use-package which-func
  :config
  ;; replace nothing found symbol "???"
  (setq which-func-unknown "∅")
  ;; add to headline
  (setq-default header-line-format
        '((which-func-mode ("" which-func-format " "))))
  ;; remove from modeline
  (setq mode-line-misc-info
    (delete '(which-function-mode (which-func-mode
                       ("" which-func-format " ")))
       mode-line-misc-info))
)

;; ==========
;; Python
;; ==========
; pip3 install python-lsp-server
(use-package eglot)

(use-package python-mode
  :ensure nil  ; in-build!
  :hook
  (python-mode . eglot-ensure)
  (python-mode . which-func-mode)
  :custom
  (python-shell-interpreter "python3")
  )
```

I also tried [that solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/70998/12999). But here is the same problem.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the previous comment, It seems hard to make a global minor mode major mode specific  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080587/make-a-global-minor-mode-buffer-local

Comment: Mhm... Then is there another way to use something like which-func-mode only in Python?

Comment: To quote that Q&A: "Global modes have to be treated on a case-by-case basis, looking at their specific implementation details."  In this particular case, it supports what you're asking for.

Comment: Make sure you get rid of `(python-mode . which-func-mode)` from your config, btw.  You don't want to be calling a global mode every time you open a python file.  Just call it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which-func[tion]-mode` does support this.

```el
(setq which-func-modes '(python-mode))
(which-func-mode 1)
```

FYI you would have found this quickly with:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `which-func` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: I rejected your proposed edit deleting the note about `customize-group`, which you described as an "unpolite RTFM".  It is not.  It is a statement of fact explicitly "for your information" intended to *help you* to learn.  I added it in part because you posted the same question *no less than three times* (twice here on E.S. and once on reddit), when the solution was there all along had you asked Emacs in the manner I've shown.  I hope that you, and anyone else who finds this answer useful in future, will add `customize-group` to your Emacs toolkit and save yourselves time and effort in future.

Comment: Furthermore a "RTFM" response (a) wouldn't provide a solution directly; (b) wouldn't have directed you to a very specific location; and (c) would refer to *documentation* rather than a customization UI; so all in all I found the comment perplexing.  You might just trust that helpful information is intended to be helpful.